# Creating user and user profile with one request which has nested JSON body in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I want to make api to create user and disease instance.

**accounts/models.py:**

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', related_name='diseases', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    arrhythmia = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

# there's no Disease's attribute in this class. 
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    identifier = models.CharField(
        max_length=User_Constant.MAX_IDENTIFIER_LENGTH,
        unique=True,
    )

    ...

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'username', ...
    ]
```

**accounts/serializers.py:**

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_disease = DiseaseSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = '__all__'


    def create(self, validated_data):
        print("validated_data : ", validated_data)
        user = MyUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        # disease_data = validated_data['disease']
        # disease = Disease.objects.create(user, **disease_data)

        return user
```

**accounts/views.py:**

```
class SignUpAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.data)
    
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()

            # After validation about user, generate token pair
            token = TokenObtainPairSerializer.get_token(user)
            refresh_token = str(token)
            access_token = str(token.access_token)

            res = Response(
                {
                    "user": serializer.data,
                    "message": "sign_up success",
                    "token": {
                        "access": access_token,
                        "refresh": refresh_token
                    }
                },
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )

            # Store JWT token in cookie
            res.set_cookie("access", access_token, httponly=True)
            res.set_cookie("refresh", refresh_token, httponly=True)

            return res
        else:
            print("is_valid() is false!")
    
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

when I'm trying to send with POST method,
This is a **JSON Content:**

```
{
  "identifier": "test1",
  "password": "test1",
  "username": "username1",
  "email": "test1@naver.com",
  "birth": "19960314",
  "gender": true,
  "isForeigner": false,
  "height": 169,
  "weight": 60,
  "pw_queiston_idx": 0,
  "pw_answer": "test_answer",
  "disease": 
  {
    "arrhythmia": true
  }
```

}

And its **response :**

```
Status: 400 Bad Request
Size: 44 Bytes
Time: 15 ms

{
  "user_disease": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}
```

**What I want to do**

1. Making api to create User record and Disease record in DB.
2. I want to know what is wrong in this code.

Could you help me out?

---

**Update:**
Actual my goal is to create Disease(kind of user profile) instance during User instance creation.

What I'm thinking:

1. Create User instance
2. With user instance, create Disease instance at the same time.
3. But I don't know the way to make Disease instance with user instance in this code.

Comment: plz add models in question for better answer

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala I added it but it's not full version. I'm sorry that I can't give u code fully cause of my job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line of your `MyUserSerializer` you actually add a required field by name `user_disease` to the `ModelSerializer`:
`user_disease = DiseaseSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)`

When you then send a request containing `disease` instead of `user_disease`, the `Serializer` rightfully complains that a required field is missing.

The `DiseaseSerializer` will also only do as advertised by default, i.e. it will only *serialize* the data, not create entries for you, you have to do this yourself:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    disease = DiseaseSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        disease_data = validated_data.pop('disease')
        user = MyUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Disease.objects.create(user=user, **disease_data)
        return user
```

You have to create the `Disease` objects after you create the `user`, otherwise the foreign key cannot be set.

Comment: Before u had answered, I implemented it what u said.
There's no way to implement what I'm thinking.
Thank you for answering my question.
I appreciated it.

Answer (score -1):

You have `user_disease` in your serializer but your are not passing it in your view, so you have two options.

Option1: Update your serializer

```py
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_disease = DiseaseSerializer(many=False, read_only=False, required=False)

    # ... rest of the serializer code ...
```

Option2: Pass `user_disease` in the request data

```json
{
  "identifier": "test1",
  "password": "test1",
  "username": "username1",
  "email": "test1@naver.com",
  "birth": "19960314",
  "gender": true,
  "isForeigner": false,
  "height": 169,
  "weight": 60,
  "pw_queiston_idx": 0,
  "pw_answer": "test_answer",
  "user_disease": {
    "arrhythmia": true
  }
}
```

Make sure to update the `user_disease` based on the fields and structure of your DiseaseSerializer.

Comment: I made a mistake to make u misunderstanding.
I uploaded early one.

Comment: My problem is that Disease model has a foreign key. During user creation, I want to use user instance to make Disease instance for connecting each other.
So in request body, I can't insert any user data.
Is there any way to solve this?